# Finding fixed points

Tags: calculus, real-analysis

I am trying to find the fixed points of the following system,

$$x'= y$$
$$y'= x \cos y$$

By setting $x'=0,y'=0$

From the first equation it gives us that $y=0$ then if $y=0$ in the first equation then since the $\cos 0=1$ then x must be $0$

So are the only fixed points from this system $(0,0),(0,1)$
?

Comment: that is the only fixed point? (0,0)?

Comment: ah no it doesn't, thanks I did not see this originally. Silly mistake

Answer (score 0):

Fixed point means that 
$$x'=x \\
y'=y$$

Setting this in your system you get
$$y=x \\
x \cos(y)=y $$

Therefore, the fixed points are given by $(y,y)$ where
$$y \cos(y)= y \Leftrightarrow y=0 \mbox{ or } \cos(y)=1$$

Comment: so then what are the fixed points? (0,0)?

Comment: @fr14 $\cos(y)=1$ has infinitely many solutions.

Comment: so then how do I show its fixed points?

Comment: @fr14 You just solve $\cos(y)=1$. You should know the solutions, they are....

Comment: yeah so if I set y to answer number besides 0 then this will not be true for x' correct?

Comment: @Moo Why do you need them equal to $0$? Fixed point means $T(z)=z$.

Comment: @fr14 What is YOUR definition of fixed point?